# iScroll4 + jQuery Mobile controls = slows down on iPad

Tags: performance, ipad, button, jquery-mobile, iscroll4

When using multiple jQuery Buttons and Checkboxes in an iScroll4 container some controls slows down: The visual feedback for the user comes late and and the transitions are not smooth.

I think its mostly an iPad performance issue, cause in the Browser everything runs fine.

Maybe there's a way to increase performance on the iPad(1)?
Has anyone a solution or a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also found this to be a problem with long list scrolling in iscroll4 and jQuery Mobile. The solution I came up with was remove jQuery Mobile from that element and the speed increased ten fold!

I then restyled the list elements to reflect the look and feel that jQuery Mobile was giving it.

I think the main reason that it slows down is because jQuery Mobile adds a lot of classes and call lots of events on touch/tap.

Comment: Hey @JakeyB, how exactly do you "remove JQuery Mobile"?  Is it not applied by default?  I like this idea, I just have no idea how to implement.  I'm also using iScroll4 and my lists are totally dragging on an iPhone 4S.